# How to join two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, syntax, mariadb, multiple-columns

I have two tables category & sub_category

category > cat_id, category_name, cat_status

sub_category > sub_cat_id, cat_name, sub_cat_name, sub_cat_status

I want to show all the columns from both tables. I have tried some joins but I am unable to do it. Here is my latest query:

```
SELECT category.category_name, category.cat_status
from category full OUTER join sub_category on category.category,
    category.cat_status, sub_category.cat_name,
    sub_category.sub_cat_name, sub_category.sub_cat_status
```

I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER join sub_category on category.category, category.cat_status , sub_categor' at line 3

Comment: Post what you have tried & in what way(s) they were deficient.

Comment: SELECT category.category_name, category.cat_status 
from category 
full OUTER join sub_category on
category.category, category.cat_status , sub_category.cat_name, sub_category.sub_cat_name, sub_category.sub_cat_status

Comment: What was wrong with the result this produced?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER join sub_category on
category.category, category.cat_status , sub_categor' at line 3

Comment: Is `cat_name` in `sub_category` the name of the super category?

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: What are you expecting as a result of this query?

Comment: from first table "category"  category_name, cat_status these two columns and all the data and after these columns from second table "sub_category" and want cat_name, sub_cat_name, sub_cat_status columns and all the data both tables have no column in common

Comment: Hi. Please read about homework at [ask] & google 'stackexhange homework'. Show what you have tried & give a [mcve]. Clarify via post edits, not comments. Also see the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also your description of what you want is too vague for anyone to know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the purpose. There are 4 types of JOIN, Left Join, Inner Join, Right Join and Full JOIN. Normally when you use any of them it is because you want to discriminate those records that are not in the two tables. For example, if I have two tables, Student and Graduate. There will be data that, are the two tables, that are in Student and not in Graduation or that are in Graduate and not Student. Then you can do.
Left JOIN to find those that are in the two tables and add those records that are NOT in Graduation but YES, in Student. Inner JOIN to only find those records that are in the two tables, that is, those that are only in a table will be discriminated. Right JOIN, the same as LEFT JOIN but with the other table and Full JOIN does not discriminate at all.

Now, to exercise a valid criterion you must choose the fields that you know that look like in the two tables, the easiest is the ID. In the case of, Student and Graduate could be the indenitty document number of a person.

In your case, I imagine that the criterion is, cat_id and sub_cat_id.

```
Select category.*, sub_category.* 
       From category inner join sub_category 
       on category.cat_id = sub_category.sub_cat_id;
```

Comment: this SQL query is working but only pulling out one data from both tables

Comment: That, is because that record matches in the two tables. That is the really purpose of JOIN clause. If you just wanna fill a table with dirty data.., you can use de full join.

Comment: Please don't guess at an unclear question, post a comment. If you don't have the rep then wait. Guesses at unclear questions make a mess.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so as `cat_name` in `sub_category` corresponds to `category_name` in `category`, you're most likely searching for:

```
SELECT *
       FROM category
            FULL JOIN sub_category
                      ON sub_category.cat_name = category.category_name;
```

**But you should not store the data like that.** Instead of having the name of the super category in the sub category's table, you should store the ID of the super category there.

Comment: Thanks you query is working with inner join with full join its giving error

Comment: i am creating database for the first time for my school project

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'category.category_name' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Bilal: So there is no column named `category_name` in `category`? Your table description lists it. (And that error should occur, if it occurs, independently from the join being inner, left, right or full.)

Comment: there is a column named category_name in category table, all i did in your query is just changed the full join to inner join and it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Bilal: Unless you found a bug in the DBMS you're using, that sounds very dubious and defies all logic. Sure you didn't accidentally leave some other characters than spaces or new lines between `category` and `FULL`, that might explain it. Otherwise I have no idea.